# How can I in Vue.js get axios response ( v-on:click ) (async / try,catch)?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, try-catch

Someone can help me, i'm trying to get object response from API whit axios in async function with try and catch.
I received: Promise { pending }.
How can i get my object?

in the template:

```
<div class="div-search-city">
  <input v-model="inputCity" placeholder="insert city name"/>
  <button id="buttonCity" @click="get()">Search city</button>
</div>
```

in the script:

```
<script>
import myFunction from './js/service.js';

export default {
  name: 'Input',
  data () {
    return {
      myData: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    get(){
      this.myData = myFunction.axiosRequest(this.inputCity);
      console.log(this.myData);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is my service.js file:

```
const axios = require('axios');

var myFunctions = {
  async axiosRequest(city){
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.waqi.info/feed/' + city + '/',
        params: {
            token: 'a1d2e0ee074e48f8bf....................'
        }
    };
    try {
      let response = await axios.request(options);
      return response
    }catch (error) {
       console.error(error)
    }
  }
}

export default myFunctions
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is to return the promise from the service.js file and doing the await in the client. After the await resolves you can set the data to the bound variable in the Vue component.

Comment: Yes, it work:
I have changed the get() function in -> async get() 
I have change the: this.myData = myFunction.axiosRequest(this.inputCity); to: this.myData = await myFunction.axiosRequest(this.inputCity);
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
import myFunction from './js/service.js';

export default {
  name: 'Input',
  data () {
    return {
      Data: {},
      
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async get(){
      this.data = await myFunction.axiosRequest(this.inputCity);
      console.log(this.data);
      
    },
  }
  
}
</script>
```